# Can a creature with Defender ninjutsu?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Satoru Umezawa](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Satoru%20Umezawa) on the table, can I ninjutsu in a [Colossus of Akros](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Colossus%20of%20Akros)? Assuming that I do have an unblocked attacker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Putting it onto the battlefield tapped and attacking is different from declaring it as an attacker, so the restriction from the keyword Defender doesn't apply in that case. (this is also why kaalia of the vast + master of cruelties works). It also means that "when this creature attacks" abilities don't trigger in that instance (which is why if you have kaalia of the vast ready to attack, you probably wouldn't want to use kaalia's ability to put aurelia the warleader out).